# Firestore get value from one document and update an existing value on another document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble getting a single value from a field of a document within Firestore. Once retrieved, I then need to set it to another field of another document within Firestore.

customerCount: 6
[image: customerCount: 6]

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const customerCount = db.collection("customers").doc("--stats--");
const customersCollection = db.collection("customers");
const customerRef = customersCollection.doc(docRef.id);
const batch = db.batch();
batch.update(customerRef, {
  customerCount: //<---get the value from firestore (see uploaded image), and set it here
});
batch.set(customerCount, { customerCount: increment }, { merge: true });
batch.commit();
```

TIA

Comment: You cannot fetch a single field. You need to get the whole document and then use your required field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not reading the `customerCount` document yet. The `customerCount` right now is just a reference to the document, but doesn't contain any data from the database yet.

```
customerCount.get().then((doc) => {
  const batch = db.batch();
  batch.update(customerRef, {
    customerCount: doc.data().customerCount + 1
  });
  batch.commit();
});
```

---

Note that there's no reason to use a batch operation here. In fact, if you want to make sure the `customerRef` and `customerCount` documents always match, this is a case where you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works fine. I do need to do it as batch as I want to set the value of a newly created document then increment the global counter but there could be other users that are submitting a form. I probably could use a transaction but it got confusing working inside of redux. Thanks again!